# How to fetch particular documents in elasticsearch index

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I want to fetch all the data of the corresponding particular field, and have a response of the elastic search.

```
{
"took": 2,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": {
        "value": 35,
        "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 0.44183275,
    "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "allevents",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "jQPDaG0BcOh3oggcguoV",
            "_score": 0.44183275,
            "_source": {
                "category": "sessions",
                 "contentid": "KqRLj2lWZ3",
                "clientname": "omkarpathlab",
------------------
}]
```

I tried **search function** it returning an error.

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
    host: 'aaa',
    log: 'trace',
    apiVersion: '7.1'
});

client.search({
    "size": 20,
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
        "default_field": "clientname",
        "query": "omkarlab"
        }
    }
     }).then((res) => {
        console.log("resultData", res);
    }, (err) => {
        console.log("err", err);
    });
enter code here
```

Error showing:

> { Error: [illegal_argument_exception] request [/_search] contains unrecognized parameter: [query]

Please suggest me how to solve this kind of problem.

Comment: WHATS THE ERROR ?

Comment: Error: [illegal_argument_exception] request [/_search] contains unrecognized parameter: [query]

Comment: are you using latest version of elasticsearch client ? as per the latest documentation you should not pass query object in json  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#_search

Comment: @mkalsi I am using latest version.could you tell me how to pass in the query object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify your field under `default_field`, not the value you are looking for. The field you are trying to query is `clientname` in your case, and the value you are looking for is `omkarpathlab`. So your query should be as follows:

```
"query": {
    "query_string": {
    "default_field": "clientname",
    "query": "omkarpathlab"
    }
}
```

edit. But your query inside of the body property:

```
client.search({
  "size": 20,
  "body": {
    "query": {
      "query_string": {
        "default_field": "clientname",
        "query": "omkarlab"
      }
    }
  }
}).then((res) => {
  console.log("resultData", res);
}, (err) => {
  console.log("err", err);
});
```

Comment: @RahulSaini could you add the exact error to your original post please?

Comment: when I use this it returns the result  
>client.search({
            index: 'allevents',
            
        }).then((res) => {
            console.log("resultData", res);
        }, (err) => {
            console.log("err", err);
        });
But did nor know how to pass query filter.

Comment: @RahulSaini i think you have to put your query inside body, can you check my updated response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to connect to elasticsearch. I have tested it on 5.6 version

```
'use strict'

const { Client } = require('@elastic/elasticsearch')
const client = new Client({ node: 'http://XXX:9200' })

async function run () {
  // Let's search!
  const { body } = await client.search({
    index: 'XXX',
    type : 'XXX',
    body: {
      query: {
       match_all: {}
      }
    }
  })

  console.log(body.hits.hits)
}

run().catch(console.log)
```

Code is a sample from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/search_examples.html site.

for search documentation check below link
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#_search

Comment: I installed elasticsearch by npm command so it showing  "elasticsearch": "^16.4.0"